# After updating to Android studio 3.5 it takes forever to build project evertime 2019

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, build.gradle

Recently i got update of android studio to version 3.5 and after updating to it now it takes too much time in everything say it gradle build or project load or new project create.

before it was working fine and done any work in seconds!!

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you upgraded to the lastest gradle and build tools as well?

Comment: yes i have upgraded everything needed